How are Momentum Range bars generated in tradovate?
Does anyone know what is the formula used by tradovate to generate their new(ish) Momentum Range chart type? I find that chart type very useful and would like to use it programatically in my code.
I can only find the general formula for generating Range charts but it is not the same
